# What does an absolute minimal PubNub service code look like?

Tags: android, pubnub

What is the minimum required code to establish a PubNub subscription in a service class? The examples on PubNub include code for on boot subscriptions, broadcast receivers, pushalarms, etc. Am I to believe that all [this](https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/tree/0dfd8028b803332f5641adc909b1a26f87bd7ff1/android/PubnubAndroid/src/com/aimx/androidpubnub) code from github is the minimum required?

The reason I ask is because I am self-learning code and having a rather rough time implementing services such as PubNub because their documentations are for a level of programmer that I haven't reached yet.

I look at the examples and try to extract just the very basic, bare necessities but I am unsure of what can be stripped from those example classes.

Thank you to someone who understands what I am trying to ask.

**EDIT:** To be clear this is my current PubNub service class:

```
public class PubNubService extends Service {

SharedPreferences sP;

static final String pub_key = " - ";
static final String sub_key = " - ";
Pubnub pubnub = new Pubnub(pub_key, sub_key, false);

String channel;
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = null;

private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        String pnMsg = msg.obj.toString();

        final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), pnMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                toast.cancel();
            }
        }, 200);

    }
};

private void notifyUser(Object message) {

    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();

    try {
        final String obj = (String) message;
        msg.obj = obj;
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
        Log.i("Received msg : ", obj.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(this, "PubnubService created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "SubscribeAtBoot");
    if (wl != null) {
        wl.acquire();
        Log.i("PUBNUB", "Partial Wake Lock : " + wl.isHeld());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Partial Wake Lock : " + wl.isHeld(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    Log.i("PUBNUB", "PubnubService created...");
    try {
        pubnub.subscribe(new String[] {channel}, new Callback() {
            public void connectCallback(String channel) {
                notifyUser("CONNECT on channel:" + channel);
            }
            public void disconnectCallback(String channel) {
                notifyUser("DISCONNECT on channel:" + channel);
            }
            public void reconnectCallback(String channel) {
                notifyUser("RECONNECT on channel:" + channel);
            }
            @Override
            public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                notifyUser(channel + " " + message.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void errorCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                notifyUser(channel + " " + message.toString());
            }
        });
    } catch (PubnubException e) {

    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (wl != null) {
        wl.release();
        Log.i("PUBNUB", "Partial Wake Lock : " + wl.isHeld());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Partial Wake Lock : " + wl.isHeld(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        wl = null;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "PubnubService destroyed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

This service above is copied from [this](https://github.com/pubnub/java/blob/master/android/examples/SubscribeAtBoot/src/com/pubnub/examples/subscribeAtBoot/PubnubService.java) example. I call to start this service from my MainActivity. I call it like this from my onCreate method:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, PubNubService.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);
```

The one thing that Android Studio yells at me for is that the Handler class should be static or leaks would occur. When I run my app, the error that occurs is: ***[Error: 128-0] : Unable to get Response Code. Please contact support with error details. Unable to resolve host "pubsub-1.pubnub.com": No address associated with hostname***. And on the next line ***[Error: 100-1] : Timeout Occurred***.

My Android Manifest has this added:

```
<service android:name=".PubNubService"/>
```

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/pubnub/java/tree/master/android/examples/PubnubExample/src/com/pubnub/examples/pubnubExample10) help at all?

Comment: I mean like in order for PubNub to be subscribed to in the background as a service. I am looking for the absolute most basic and useless code so I can see how to properly structure the service so it will work, then I can add my own code to the base

Answer (score 0):

### PubNub Minimal Android Sample Code to Publish & Subscribe

The simplest sort of example would be to just add all the code in a single Activity. All of the following code and be seen in [PubNub Android SDK docs page](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/data-streams-publish-and-subscribe).

```
import com.pubnub.api.*;
import org.json.*;


Pubnub pubnub = new Pubnub("your_pub_key", "your_sub_key");

pubnub.subscribe("channel1", new Callback() {
      @Override
      public void connectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
          System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : CONNECT on channel:" + channel
                     + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                     + message.toString());
      }

      @Override
      public void disconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
          System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : DISCONNECT on channel:" + channel
                     + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                     + message.toString());
      }

      public void reconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
          System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : RECONNECT on channel:" + channel
                     + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                     + message.toString());
      }

      @Override
      public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
          System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : " + channel + " : "
                     + message.getClass() + " : " + message.toString());
          // this is the messages received from publish
          // add these messages to a list UI component
      }

      @Override
      public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
          System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : ERROR on channel " + channel
                     + " : " + error.toString());
      }
    }
  );
```

Callback callback = new Callback() {
  public void successCallback(String channel, Object response) {
    System.out.println(response.toString());
  }
  public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
    System.out.println(error.toString());
  }
};
pubnub.publish("my_channel", "Hello from the PubNub Java SDK!" , callback);

You might have to make a few changes. For one, you should create a click method with the publish inside it that is bound to a button on your interface. And as noted in the successCallback for the subscribe method, you need to display the messages in a UI component on your Activity.

That should do it for you.

#### Subscribe at Boot

But there isn't really anything simpler than our [Subscribe at Boot sample app](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/380/can-my-android-app-receive-messages-while-inactive) that uses a Service to forward messages as Intents to an Activity.

**Prevent Service Start on Device Boot**

The fact that the Subscribe at Boot example starts up when the device is booted (powered on) is a matter of configuration. You can change the manifest so that it is only started when the app is started. See the SO thread [Trying to start a service on boot on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android) and undo the parts that make it start at boot.

This is full of helpful information on [Android Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

More details on this in this SO thread "[Is leaving a pubnub subscription open in a service optimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35051528/is-leaving-a-pubnub-subscription-open-in-a-service-optimal)"

Comment: I am looking for an example that is exactly like the Subscribe at Boot example, except that I do not want to subscribe at boot. I want to subscribe (start the service) from within an activity after a user has pushed a button. Is there an easy way to modify the Subscribe at Boot code so that it doesn't subscribe at boot but on choice?
** Just to clarify -- I already know how to subscribe and use PubNub while the app is running. I am looking for a way to subscribe to PubNub in a _service_ (aka in the background).

Comment: See the "Prevent Service Start on Device Boot" section I ended to the end of my answer. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Unable to get Response Code - this is a network connection error of some sort. And just a heads up, with Android 5, the background service is something you might not be able to do anymore and GCM may be your only choice. I will have an Android engineer review this for further insights for you.

Comment: Okay thanks, for the network connection error, is there anything that I should look out for that might have caused it? Things I might have missed?

Comment: Also, am I to understand that there isn't a way to keep PubNub running in the background service on newer devices?

Comment: It's not PubNub issue but rather Android Services in general and keeping a socket open in Service in background. See this SO thread that is very similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35051528/is-leaving-a-pubnub-subscription-open-in-a-service-optimal